# How do I use a field to populate the mail.setToAddresses in a sendEmail class

Tags: apex, soql, query, visualforce-template

I have set up a class that sends an email and I am using a VF Email Template that uses the Oppertunity fields.  I have set up a custom field called Proposals_Senders_Email__c that is a text field.

I want to use Proposals_Senders_Email__c and the setToAddresses in my APEX class.

do I need to do a Query like this?

```
Opportunity o = [Select Proposals_Senders_Email__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id=: OpportunityId];
```

Here is my code, I have been trying lots of things so I have had to comment out lots of things, for testing. Thank you.

```
 global class proteusProposalCon {
  global ApexPages.StandardController controller;
  global proteusProposalCon(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
  }

    global PageReference saveAndCongrat() {
    controller.save(); // This takes care of the details for you.
    PageReference congratsPage = Page.thankyou;
    congratsPage.setRedirect(true);
    return congratsPage;
  }
  global List<Opportunity> listOfOpportunity {get; set;}
  global Opportunity OpportunityObj {get;set;}

  Webservice static void sendEmailFunction(){
    //Opportunity o = [Select Id, Contact_Name__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id=: OpportunityId];

    //String ProteusStaffName = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('VFname');
    String ProteusStaffEmail = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('VFemail');

     Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

     String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'XXX@YYY.com'};

     //String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'XXX@YYY.com'}; 

    //String ProteusStaffName = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('VFname');
     //String[] ProteusStaffName2 = new String[] {ProteusStaffName};
     //String[] ccAddresses = new String[] {'XXX@YYY.com'};
     mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);

     // Assume the record ID is contained in the the parameter named "id"

    Id WhatId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    Id UserIdVar = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('userId');



    String myUserIdString = UserIdVar;
    // Set the target object ID on the email object
    mail.setWhatId(WhatId);
    mail.setTargetObjectId(myUserIdString);
    mail.saveAsActivity = false;

     mail.setReplyTo('info@proteusleadership.com');
     mail.setSenderDisplayName('Proteus Leadership');

     mail.setBccSender(false);
     mail.setUseSignature(false);  

     mail.setTemplateId('00X90000001FPod');


     if (!Test.IsRunningTest()) Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });


   } 


}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a template, then you simply cannot use `setToAddresses`, `setBccAddresses` or `setCcAddresses`. If the person being emailed is also a contact, lead or user, then you can use `targetObjectId`, or `targetObjectIds`. Otherwise, I'm sorry but I do not know of any clean way around that restriction. [Source](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setToAddresses)

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me, that is why it wouldn't work.  So If I wasn't going to use a template and if I wanted to use the setTextBody how would 
I go about it?  Thank you.

Comment: In that case you would need to build up the body by either concatenating strings and values together or using String.Format(String, List<String>) to send via setHtmlBody or setPlainTextBody.

Comment: Bob -- the doc is wrong; you can most definitely setToAddresses(), setBccAddresses(), and setCcAddresses() with a template. I've posted a doc feedback with SFDC on this point. See http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/32102/2602

Comment: So if it is possible, how do I do it? I will need to make a list with a SOQL query and then how do I call the field?